# GitHub version control not working as expected

Tags: git, bash, github, version-control

Code at bottom

I am using a private repo on GitHub as a version control between me and a partner and I am having some difficulties in my approach. I have wrote a few bash scripts as a way of streamlining the process. Essentially I envisioned three bash scripts: get latest (GL), check-out (CKO), and commit (CM). We have both set up a directory structure as such, `usr/documents/opsys/` and initialized a git repo on our own separate machines in the same way.

```
cd usr/documents/opsys/
git init
git remote add origin https://YOURUSER:YOURPW@github.com/louis-krueger/OpSys.git
git pull origin master
```

My idea is to be able to log into our machine and run

```
cd usr/documents/opsys/
```

After we are in the directory I intended for us to share/have in common. Here we have the bash scripts in. Running `ls` returns the following:

```
CKO  CM  GL  README.md  testkill  xinu-hw3
```

The idea worked, I was able to "GL", check out a working branch for my current work period, and then I could check in the changes to the branch when I was done. Then I manually merged my solo work, and deleted the dead branch. This worked like I wanted it too until I tried showing my partner it. I think the main issue is within my get latest. After we log in and switch our working directory to `opsys/` we want to be able to run ./GL and anything in the directory which is not in the latest master commit should be deleted from the local machine and `ls opsys/` should look exactly like what you would expect to get back from a theoretical "ls origin master"

```
CKO  CM  GL  README.md   xinu-hw3
```

I expected that `testkill` would have disappeared, but it didn't.

At the end of the day, ideally this would be my envisioned work flow (ASCII graphic)

```
Day 1
AM                         Noon                   3am(stuck here)

me             ----function1.c--------------------- 
              /
master ------/------------shared unmodified files-- 
                   \
partner             \ -------function2.c-----------


Day 2
        3am     morning  (**action here, see below)           

me      --(f1)---------------\ 
                              \
master  --unmodified common----|--all common---master--------- 
                              /
partner --(f2)---------------/
```

**action: After we have completed our separate work, I would like to be able to manually merge our branches back to the master so the next time we sign on we can ./GL and BAM we both see the same thing when GL checks out master. Preferably both of the branches disappear(or is there a way to cut them down and store them behind the shed?...archive).

Needed (criticism && suggestions == true), it will be imperative that we have a quick way to share are work while working remotely from each other.

### **EOT**

---

*code snippets*

### GL

```
#!/bin/bash
# @author Louis Krueger - 01/2016
#
# Get latest script
#

REMOTE_VERIFY="git remote -v"

echo "Git Latest"
echo "Please enter username:"
read user
if [ -n "$user" ]; then
        echo "enter pw:"
        read pw
else
        echo "username is nothing, exiting..."
        exit 1;
fi
if [ -n REMOTE_VERIFY ]; then
        git remote set-url origin https://$user:$pw@github.com/louis-krueger/Opsys.git
else
        git remote add origin https://$user:$pw@github.com/louis-krueger/OpSys.git
fi
git pull origin master
echo "$USER  up-to-date"
```

### CKO

```
#!/bin/bash
# @author Louis Krueger - 01/2016
# Check out/create branch for current work
#


echo "Ready to work? Checking out branch"
echo "Please enter branch name:"
read branch
if [ -n "$branch" ]; then
        echo "creating branch!"
else
        echo "invalid branch name, exiting..."
        exit 1;
fi
git checkout -b $branch
git push origin $branch
echo "new branch ($branch) has been created"
```

### CM

```
#!/bin/bash
# @author Louis Krueger - 01/2016
#
# Commit branch script
#
error="0"
echo "Are you sure you would like to commit and switch to master?(y/n)"
read confirm
if [ $confirm = "y" ]&&[ $error="0" ]; then
        echo "enter commit message:" 
        read message
        if [ -n "$message" ]&&[ $error="0" ]; then
                echo "enter branch name:"
                read branch
                if [ -n "$branch" ]; then
                        git pull
                        git add ./
                        git commit -m "$message"
                else
                        error="1"
                fi
        else
                error="1"
        fi
else
        error="1"
fi
if [ "$error" = "1" ]; then
        echo "You seem unsure Sire. Perhaps its time to get some fresh air... exiting. No changes have been made"
        exit 1;
fi
git push origin $branch
echo "switching to master"
git checkout master
echo "your branch ($branch) has been commited to the repo, contact admin for master&branch merge"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After we log in and switch our working directory to `opsys/` we want to be able to run ./GL and anything in the directory which is not in the latest master commit should be deleted from the local machine...

The commands to do this are:

```
git fetch;
git reset --hard origin/master;
```

`git fetch` retrieves the latest copy of the repository from the remote, and `git reset --hard origin/master` resets all files in the repository to that state, destroying all changes.

NB: This won't remove untracked files; to do that as well, add a `rm -rf *` before the `git reset`. If your repository contains dotfiles, you'll need to account for them in the `rm` command as well (remember not to delete `.git`!).

Alternately, you could just `rm opsys/` and `git clone https://YOURUSER:YOURPW@github.com/louis-krueger/OpSys.git`. That would discard any local files and get you a fresh copy of the repository, but could be slow if your repository is large.

---

> After we have completed our separate work, I would like to be able to manually merge our branches back to the master....
>
> Preferably both of the branches disappear...

To merge your branch into master, just `git checkout master` then `git merge branchname`. You can then delete the local branch with `git branch -d branchname`.